# how do I show the box with all modifiers (Blender 4.0)?

Tags: modifiers, interface

How do I show the box with all modifiers? This is what appears now

[image]

Comment: They changed this in 4.0, you now have them grouped in categories. Like the ones that before were above the columns as a title.

Comment: Either start typing the name of the modifier you want or click on one of the entries to show the whole list for that category.